# AWS Cognito with Azure AD gets mismatched reply URL every time

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-cognito, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to use AWS Cognito with a user pool using Azure AD as an Identity Provider (OpenID Connect).

I set up the User Pool in Cognito and specify the callback URL of my test app (https://localhost:44381) and I configure an App Registration in Azure AD that has the same URL in the Redirect URIs.

In the AWS Console, under App Client Settings, I click "Launch Hosted UI" to test it. It displays a page that lets me choose my configured Identity Provider (Azure AD).  On that page, I can see in the URL what it has for "&redirect_uri=".  It has https://mydomain.auth.us-east-2.amazaoncognito.com/oauth2/.

So I put that URL in both AWS Cognito and in Azure AD as the Callback URI/Redirect URI.

Then when I click through to the Identity Provider, it pops up the normal Azure AD login and lets me log in, but I get:

AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application: '60e47fff-e2cc-41d8-8405-283bafb33fbb'.

This is the application (client) ID from Azure AD.

Likewise, when I run this from my test app, I can see the redirect_uri=https://localhost:44381/oidc in the URL - but same thing happens - redirect mismatch. Though that exact URL is in both AWS and Azure AD.

How can I find out what it is trying to "match"? It's obviously changing something in the URL that I give it.

Comment: The error you get from AAD gives the reply url that it’s trying to match.

Comment: What did you set in AAD app registration? `https://localhost:44381/oidc` or `https://localhost:44381`? You should make sure they are totally the same.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Yes, I realize that it is AAD giving the reply, but there is no way to see what Cognito is actually sending that does not match. In AWS Cognito->User Pools->Federated Identities, I have "https://localhost:44381/oidc" entered in the field Callback URL(s), and have "Authorization code grant" and "Implicit grant" checked under Allowed Flows. In AAD->App Registrations->Authentication I have that exact same URL entered under Web-Redirect URIs "https://localhost:44381/oidc". But it still gets a redirect mismatch.

Comment: @AllenWu I have https://localhost:44381/oidc, and the exact same thing entered in Cognito in App Client Settings->Callback URLs.

Comment: I've made a little progress - I added options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-oidc"), and used "/signin-oidc" in the URI in AWS and AAD. I'm getting a different error, and I see this logged in AAD "The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.".  This is confusing because I have tried setting "options.ClientSecret " in my code, but it doesn't change anything. I can't tell if this is supposed to be the AWS User Pool secret or the AAD secret in App Registrations.

Comment: " I realize that it is AAD giving the reply, but there is no way to see what Cognito is actually sending that does not match." The reply URL AAD shows in the error IS the url AWS sent to AAD. AAD complains saying "I dont know this URL". So you copy the URL in the error and put it inside the AAD App reg. If the new error is coming from AAD (AADSTS000000), then AAD is telling you, that this app is a Web App (.Net/server side), referring to AWS App. And that it should be sending a client_secret. That secret is generated on the Azure AD App registration, and given to AWS to send to AAD.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Thanks. I *think* I'm getting a successful login now (In the Sign-ins log in the Azure portal, I see Status "Success" under Basic info). However, the error that comes back to my app is "invalid request" with the message "AzureADOIDC Error - 401 error getting token" - where AzureADOIDC is the name I gave the Identity Provider in AWS.

Comment: @mannaggia Having the same issue you mentioned in your last comment. Did you ever find a solution?